# Print varchar in Pro*c from Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, printf, procedure, proc

I need get the output of a VARCHAR2  variable in PRO*C. This variable  comes from a Oracle procedure. This is the thing:

This work fine,

```
bzero(d_fecha_ejecucion.arr,20); 
 EXEC SQL SELECT
 TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') INTO :d_fecha_ejecucion FROM
 DUAL;           
 sprintf(c_msg,"--->FECHA EJECUCIÓN: [%s]",(char *)d_fecha_ejecucion.arr);
```

But when I try to get a variable (VARCHAR SV_desc_error) from procedure like this:

```
 EXEC SQL EXECUTE
 BEGIN
 PACKAGE.PROCEDURE_PR(:SN_num_ev, :SN_cod_msjerror,:SV_desc_error);
 END;
END-EXEC;

bzero(SV_desc_error.arr,4000);
SV_desc_error.len = (unsigned short)strlen((char *)SV_desc_error.arr);

sprintf(c_msg,"--->Out PACKAGE.PROCEDURE_PR(SN_num_ev: [%d],SN_cod_msjerror: [%d],SV_desc_error: [%s])",SN_num_evento,SN_cod_msjerror,(char *)SV_desc_error.arr);
```

Don't work...the variable return empty

I test with a anonymous block and works...

So, who i can get this variable?
Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are setting "bzero" AFTER your code execution, which should be wiping out any value you might have returned.

Correct this and rerun.

Comment: I'm embarrassed, if that. Thank you. Do not use drugs.